# animate - scrollTop in Css

Tags: jquery, html, css, amp-html

I have a table of contents with html that when I click on send me the subtitle h1, h2 ect ..

```
<div class="idc-box">
<p class="idc-titulo">Contents</p>
<ul class="idc-lista">
  <li ><a href="#indice1">1 Índice 1</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#subindice1">1.1 Subíndice 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#subindice2">1.2 Subíndice 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<h2 class="stitulo" id="indice1"><span class="titulo">Indice 1</span></h2>
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
<h3 id="subindice1">Subindice 1.1</h3>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 

<h3 id="subindice2">Subindice 1.2</h3>
asda
<div>
```

In jquery when I want to put a space above the title or subtitle I used animate - scrollTop :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#idc-box a").click(function(e){


    var enlace = $(this).attr('href');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($(enlace).offset().top - 90) + 'px'
    }, 500)
})
</script>
```

but now I can not use query if not CSS because I'm using AMP = = Accelerated Mobile Pages
How can I do that equivalent in CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a back-to-top button using CSS and HTML only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102747/how-to-make-a-back-to-top-button-using-css-and-html-only)

Comment: it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question? It appears to be unclear or missing some information. What exactly is the problem of your code or app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a native CSS feature that controls scroll behaviour without having to use jQuery, called [`scroll-behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior):

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.scrolling-box {
  scroll-behavior: smooth; // Animates scrolling - "smooth" scrolling
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-box">
  <a href="#1">1</a>
  <a href="#2">2</a>
  <a href="#3">3</a>
  <section id="1">This is the first section</section>
  <section id="2">This is the second section</section>
  <section id="3">This is the third section</section>
</div>
```