# How to go about merging an onclick Event and Scroll To Top

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to coding and recently had a website built for me. I am having trouble merging two different javascript codes together. This is the first javascript code, which allows me to open an event.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
 
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

The next code allows me to scroll to the top of the page on click. It's able to be made into an OnClick function.

```js
var scrollToTop = window.setInterval(function() {
    var pos = window.pageYOffset;
    if ( pos > 0 ) {
        window.scrollTo( 0, pos - 20 ); // how far to scroll on each step
    } else {
        window.clearInterval( scrollToTop );
    }
}, 16); // how fast to scroll (this equals roughly 60 fps)
```

I am asking how to make merge these codes together so when I click on an image, I am brought to that event AND I am scrolled to the top of the page. They work separately but I want them together. I've had issues with other codes such as the page refreshing to the top, but I'm not shown the event. Without scroll to the top the event is shown as where you are on the screen. I am very new to coding and know very little so I apologize if this is a really simple question. Thank you everyone!

EDIT: Figured out a soltuion. Simply paste

```html
, document.body.scrollTop=0;document.documentElement.scrollTop=0;event.preventDefault()
```

into your onclick attribute seperated by a comma.

Comment: you could just add <a href="#top"></a> outside the element with the onClick function and it should do the same thing as your scroll to top script.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am having an issue with this. When I put that in it opens a new tab, and it also doesn't open the new event. The old tab also does not take me to the top. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: hmm, you might have target="_blank" defined for all a tags somewhere in your code then, try adding target="_self" to the a tag and maybe try adding OnClick="OpenCity()" aswell to the a tag instead of the other element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the answer to my question while browsing similar questions. I used @spacer GIF's answer from this question. - [How to make a back-to-top button using CSS and HTML only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102747/how-to-make-a-back-to-top-button-using-css-and-html-only)

Simply put a comma after the original event and paste the follow:

```html
document.body.scrollTop=0;document.documentElement.scrollTop=0;event.preventDefault()
```

It should look like this. Here is a working example from my website.

```html
   <a onclick="openCity(event, 'CMK'), document.body.scrollTop=0;document.documentElement.scrollTop=0;event.preventDefault()" class="square" style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/rtBFTGq/C.png');width: 9%;"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put `scrollToTop()` at the end of `openCity`:

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  scrollToTop();
}
```

This assumes some things about the structure of your code (namely that `scrollToTop` is in scope within that function), but it should probably work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Sadly this did not work. Do you happen to have any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? It didn't scroll?

Comment: No, it did not scroll. Nothing on my end changed. Does it have anything to do with }
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click(); at the end of my script?

Comment: I think you haven't provided enough code to assess the problem, which is probably pretty simple. My suggestion will cause (should cause) the page to scroll to the top when clicking on a tab. Is that what you want?

Comment: OK, though if it takes more than 15 minutes to debug it, I'll have to drop it. I have a real job... :)

Comment: Before I do it, please check if you have any javascript errors in the console.

Comment: Keep in mind that with this code you still need to have the ScrollToTop() function defined in the other javascript file.

Comment: @Blomqen is right (or may be depending on the javascript) - that's why I asked about errors. If you see "scrollToTop" is not a function, then you may need to copy the function over.